# Processing GRIB2 file in memory

Tags: julia, grib

I'm currently downloading a GRIB2 file and parsing it with the GRIB library:

```
using GRIB

url = "https://mtarchive.geol.iastate.edu/2022/01/01/mrms/ncep/MultiSensor_QPE_01H_Pass2/MultiSensor_QPE_01H_Pass2_00.00_20220101-000000.grib2.gz"
run(`curl -O "$(url)"`)
results = GribFile("MultiSensor_QPE_01H_Pass2_00.00_20220101-000000.grib2.gz")
```

This works fine, but I'd like to process it in memory instead.

I've made many attempts but with no success, for example:

```
url = "https://mtarchive.geol.iastate.edu/2022/01/01/mrms/ncep/MultiSensor_QPE_01H_Pass2/MultiSensor_QPE_01H_Pass2_00.00_20220101-000000.grib2.gz"
data = String(HTTP.get(url))
buffer = IOBuffer(data)
results = GribFile(buffer)
```

Comment: Because of buffering on the OS level, after reading a small enough file, it will reside in memory anyway, so the speed benefit may not be so great.
You can also save the file in a temporary name using `mktemp` (see docs in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Filesystem ). And the file can be removed after reading. Again, the overhead is not too critical (unless repeated many times).
As for the library GRIB.jl itself, it doesn't seem to support this method of direct input from IOBuffer.

Comment: Thanks @DanGetz, I'm afraid you're right.  I'll be downloading 100,000+ GRIB2 files and adding them to a database, and I've calculated it will take about 10 days to do so.  I'm using a RAM disk (/dev/shm), which helps a bit.  But if I could save a second or two per file by sending the data directly to `GribFile()`, that could save me a day or two.

Comment: But great point about the file contents staying in memory.  I could output it to the same filename each time instead of removing the file once processed.  That could save some time.

Comment: Having looked at the URL with the file you had in the OP, I can see there are a great many files there. I believe the bottleneck is downloading and not the storage space or loading from file to memory time. For best results, I would 100% (or even more % ;-) download all the data locally, to have it processed later by a program. Remember, programs have bugs, so it is likely the files will need to be reprocessed several times.

Comment: Yep, I had already started doing that after determining there was no advantage to saving to the same file name.  That means I can't take advantage of the RAM disk, but my SSD is fast enough.